# All Chrome open window names in VBA

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a macro on VBA in the process of which several Chrome windows open.
In each of the windows I need to do different actions and for this I need to switch between them.
Can I somehow get a list of the names of the open Chrome windows or their handles in the VBA?
Such methods did not work in VBA:

```
driver.getWindowHandles
driver.getWindowNames
```

In JS, you can get the window name:

```
window_name = driver.ExecuteScript("return window.name;")
```

Perhaps there is a way to get the names of all the windows and cycle through them in the VBA?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to more or less resolve this issue.

We save the name of each window to be opened in a variable

```
window_count = driver.Windows.Count 'count all chrome windows

i = 0
For i = 1 To window_count 
    If driver.Windows.item(i).Title <> "SomeTitle 1" And driver.Windows.item(i).Title <> "SomeTitle 2" Then
        window_name = driver.Windows.item(i).Title 'at this moment the desired window is 
                                           'activated and you can work in it even
                                           'without driver.SwitchToWindowByTitle
         MsgBox driver.URL
    End If
Next i
```

I think this is not the best solution to the problem, but with my knowledge it’s better to do so far I can’t